# last_analyzed for foreign tables

Tags: postgresql

Which view can be queried to get the date when statistics have been calculated for the last time on foreign tables. For standard tables I use *pg_stat_all_tables* catalog view (*last_analyze* field), for foreign tables this view does not return any information.

```
foo [16250]=# select schemaname, relname, last_vacuum,
last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze from
pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'my_foreign_table';
┌────────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ schemaname │ relname │ last_vacuum │ last_autovacuum │ last_analyze │ last_autoanalyze │
├────────────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
└────────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┘
(0 rows)
```

Comment: I don't think Postgres keeps statistics on foreign tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_stat_all_tables` only lists relations with `pg_class.relkind = ANY(ARRAY['r'::"char", 't'::"char", 'm'::"char"])`, which is why your foreign table (with `relkind='f'`) does not appear - you can see this with `\d+ pg_stat_all_tables` in psql. . However, if the foreign data wrapper in question supports ANALYZE, you can use `pg_stat_get_last_analyze_time(oid)` with the foreign table to get what you're looking for.

```
testdb=# \d+ t_f_f
                                     Foreign table "public.t_f_f"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | FDW options | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 x      | text |           |          |         |             | extended |              | 
Server: loopback_5436
FDW options: (table_name 't_f')

testdb=# select pg_stat_get_last_analyze_time('t_f_f'::regclass);
 pg_stat_get_last_analyze_time 
-------------------------------
 2021-08-31 07:03:38.6269-07
(1 row)

testdb=# analyze t_f_f;
ANALYZE
testdb=# select pg_stat_get_last_analyze_time('t_f_f'::regclass);
 pg_stat_get_last_analyze_time 
-------------------------------
 2021-08-31 07:10:00.030256-07
(1 row)
```